# In the "preview app", filters don't update

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a number of filters in the "preview app", at https://app.snowflake.com/us-east-1/xxx/admin/settings.  The filters work well in charts but don't update as the UI indicates they would.  The content of the filters needs to get updated over time because there will be new entries, so the queries are set to update daily (BTW, what time daily?) and the database to query against is set correctly.  But the updates don't happen.  Is there something else that needs to be set up to do this?

(I am not an admin, but can ask for admin steps to be taken if needed.)

Comment: can you provide a detailed example of what you think should be happening vs. what is happening?  Your post doesn't provide enough detail.

Comment: Assuming new data was added, are you pressing the run/update button on the dashboard to refresh and it doesn't work to get the latest filter results?  Do you have a screenshot of one of your simpler filters with its logic? If you edit the filter and save it again, does it then update? If the latter, then this is probably worth opening a case with support to share your use case.

Comment: More specifics:  One of the filters is to allow a user to pick a forecast date.  As new forecasts are created, there are new forecast dates in the table.  So there is a filter with the query `select distinct fcst_date from forecasts.v_object_forecasts_v2 order by fcst_date desc`.  In the "Configure filter" dialog, the correct database is set and the "Refresh daily" option is chosen.  But the filter is not refreshed daily; the values are always the same until I go and refresh it manually.

Comment: Reply to Suzy Lockwood:  That's right.  There is new data in the table, but the filter is not updated unless I manually edit and resave it.